# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 433: ordinal not in range(128) when creating a conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ascii, conda

So I am using a server machine and I am not a sudoer there. Is there any way I could fix this error without being a sudoer?

```
[jalal@scc2 jalal]$ pwd
/projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal



[jalal@scc2 jalal]$ conda env create -p /projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal/dpk  -f test-dlc.yaml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.5
  latest version: 4.7.12

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



Downloading and Extracting Packages
python-3.6.8         | 30.1 MB   | ######################################################################################################################################################################## | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal/dpk/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal/condaenv.z3h62tjp.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting opencv-python==3.4.5.20
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/e1/d3eed618272f4b746339af1a84b2511e79c1708d88a9195cf25d743fa614/opencv_python-3.4.5.20-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.4MB)
Collecting deeplabcut
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/70/496226dbc1d22ab5e5af396d483910522b583389d5948e75db9ac4a7ef9c/deeplabcut-2.1.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting matplotlib==3.0.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/69/f5e05f578585ed9935247be3788b374f90701296a70c8871bcd6d21edb00/matplotlib-3.0.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting tables==3.4.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/96/fdfaae19cf3c292c54e8b21dbc723a19871a767d4fa063d927ca05982409/tables-3.4.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/b1/0ad4ae02e17ddd62109cd54c291e311c4b5fd09b4d0678d3d6ce4159b0f0/tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (345.2MB)
Collecting imgaug
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/df/5a3bba95b4600d5ca7aff072082ef0d9837056dd28cc4e738e7ce88dd8f8/imgaug-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/df/0f5dd132200728a86190397e1ea87cd76244e42d39ec5e88efd25b2abd7e/jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting deepposekit
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/2f/f1f9d7f71f16b2c723d02f043d39e697256cf7d8b21f78b2bae066a1e334/deepposekit-0.3.4.tar.gz

Pip subprocess error:
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal/dpk/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/scratch/pip-install-523js4rg/deepposekit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/scratch/pip-install-523js4rg/deepposekit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /scratch/pip-install-523js4rg/deepposekit/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /scratch/pip-install-523js4rg/deepposekit/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/scratch/pip-install-523js4rg/deepposekit/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        long_description=open("README.md").read(),
      File "/projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal/dpk/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 433: ordinal not in range(128)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.


CondaEnvException: Pip failed

[jalal@scc2 jalal]$ pwd
/projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal
[jalal@scc2 jalal]$ cat test-dlc.yaml
# dlc-ubuntu-GPU.yaml
#
# DeepLabCut environment for Ubuntu (tested on 18.04)
#
# install: conda env create -f dlc-ubuntu-GPU.yaml
# update:  conda env update -f dlc-ubuntu-GPU.yaml

#DeepLabCut2.0 Toolbox (deeplabcut.org)
#© A. & M. Mathis Labs
#https://github.com/AlexEMG/DeepLabCut
#Please see AUTHORS for contributors.

#https://github.com/AlexEMG/DeepLabCut/blob/master/AUTHORS
#Licensed under GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0

name: dlc-ubuntu-GPU
channels:
  - anaconda-fusion
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pip
  - python=3.6.8
  - pip:
    - opencv-python==3.4.5.20
    - deeplabcut
    - matplotlib==3.0.3
    - tables==3.4.3
    - tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
    - imgaug
    - jupyter
    - deepposekit
    - https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-18.04/wxPython-4.0.3-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

For example I see this github solution but it does require sudo access:
https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome/issues/4#issuecomment-218441687

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
Release:    7.5.1804
Codename:   Core


$ uname -a
Linux scc2 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared a dependency to [DeepPoseKit](https://github.com/jgraving/DeepPoseKit) which tries setting its [`long_description` by reading the project's `README.md`](https://github.com/jgraving/DeepPoseKit/blob/bdfcd238e2d6171653d2844588bfe02b3406ee37/setup.py#L42). For whatever reason that `README.md` contains non ASCII characters around position `433`, which causes the python decoder to fail while executing the `setup.py`.

*A*: Please open an issue or pull request for this in the [DeepPoseKit Repository](https://github.com/jgraving/DeepPoseKit). They are the only ones who can fix this issue properly.

The actual problem with the package is in this part of the [README.md](https://github.com/jgraving/DeepPoseKit/blame/master/README.md#L10):

```
using deep learning—written in Python
```

the `—` (U+2014) is a non ASCII character.

Until the maintainers of the package fix this issue, you can apply the following workaround:

1. Create a conda environment without DeepPoseKit
2. Enter that conda environment
3. Clone the repository: `git clone git@github.com:jgraving/DeepPoseKit.git`
4. Truncate the `README.md`: `echo > README.md`
5. Install the dependency manually: `python setup.py install`

---

#### Update

This should be fixed and merged with this [pull request](https://github.com/jgraving/DeepPoseKit/pull/36)